# Regex picking up string that contain 2 dash

Tags: regex

I am new to regrex.
Will want to pick up a list of bank number with many others text in it.

The bank number can be e.g 111-123456-1 or 111-12345-1 or 111-1-123456

How should i write this regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use `\d+-\d+-\d+`. However you should try something before post a question here.

Comment: Hi i did try with a few like
([\d]{3}-[\d]{5,6}-\d)
([\d]{3}-[\d]{6}-\d)
But i think i complicated thing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression

```
\d+-\d+-\d+
```

It will match the bank numbers that you gave as examples:

```
111-123456-1   // Matches
111-12345-1    // Matches
111-1-123456   // Matches
```

If you want a better understanding of the regex, check this out:
https://regex101.com/r/ncPZoQ/1

Credits to @ALFA